# Advantage Database Server ORDER BY behaviour

Tags: select, sql-order-by, advantage-database-server

I'm using ADS v10 beta. I'm trying to numerate ordered resultset.

1) ORDER BY in nested queries. I need to use nested SELECT for some calculations:

```
SELECT Name, Value, ROWNUM() FROM (SELECT * FROM MainTable WHERE Value > 0 ORDER BY Value) a
```

And I'm getting

```
Expected lexical element not found: )
There was a problem parsing the table
names after the FROM keyword in your
SELECT statement.
```

Everything is working well when the ORDER BY is removed. Although, I found the sample in the Help, it looks like my query (more complex, indeed):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 10 empid, fullname FROM branch1 ORDER BY empid) a UNION SELECT empid, fullname FROM branch2 ORDER BY empid
```

2) `ORDER BY` + `ROWNUM()`. I used the nested query in the example above, to numerate ordered rows. Is there are any chance to avoid nested query?
In the SQL Server I can do something like this:

```
SELECT Name, Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Value) FROM MainTable WHERE Value > 1 ORDER BY Value
```

Please advice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to move the ORDER BY outside the subquery:

```
SELECT Name, Value, ROWNUM() FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM MainTable WHERE Value > 0 ) a ORDER BY Value
```

If you are wanting the rownum() to be applied to the ordered result set (I'm a bit slow this morning), then it might be necessary to use something like the following:

```
SELECT Name, Value, ROWNUM() FROM 
  (SELECT top 100 PERCENT * FROM MainTable WHERE Value > 0 order by value ) a
```

I don't think the ORDER BY in the subquery is allowed unless it actually changes the result ... however in this case, it does seem like it should be allowed.

Comment: Your suggestion could be simplified to 

"SELECT Name, Value, ROWNUM() FROM MainTable WHERE Value > 0 ORDER BY Value"

Isn't it?

In second "2)" part of my question I wrote why it doesn't work.

Comment: @ie:  Yes it is equivalent to that query.  However, I don't believe the OVER clause is supported (in the second query).

Comment: @Mark Wilkins: as for TOP 100 PERCENT, don't you think that such demand look like a bug? I mean that I expect to see all 100 percent of records in any way.

Comment: @ie: I agree that the TOP usage is very artificial in this case. Can you clarify what you are trying to do with the ROWNUM() in this situation? Does it need to be applied to the ordered result set?

Comment: @Mark Wilkins: it is a quite special case, I need to split an ordered recordset in two - one with odd rownum and another one with even. Then I need to make some calculations with them.
To simplify this, let say that I need to perform operations with 1st and 2nd records, 3rd and 4th, etc. in ordered recordset. Using of the rownum is not the only way to do it, but I was trying this one.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use aliases in your statements to make it clearer, and probably to solve the issue.

Rather than:

```
SELECT Name, Value, ROWNUM() 
FROM (SELECT * FROM MainTable WHERE Value > 0 ORDER BY Value) a
```

Use

```
SELECT a.Name, a.Value, ROWNUM() 
FROM (SELECT mt.* FROM MainTable mt WHERE mt.Value > 0 ORDER BY mt.Value) a
```

The problem might be that it is confusing the field `value` in the `order by` clause -- it does not know which table to get it from, the 1st or 2nd.

Comment: 1st or 2nd? Why? I'm using only one table.

Comment: Your questions seems to have changed dramatically since I answered.  But in your original query 'a' is one set of records and maintable is another set of records.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you are talking about.